# I'm trying to make a java program that creates passwords

Tags: java

I think I have everything working except for one thing. When I call the method more than once on main it keeps creating the same password.

Here's the class for the password creation:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PasswordRandomizer {
    // Define the variables
    private int length;
    private String password;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private char symbol;

    public PasswordRandomizer(int length) {
        // Initialize the variable
        password = "";
        this.length = length;
        while (this.password.length() < this.length) {
            this.symbol = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(this.random.nextInt(25));
            this.password += symbol;
        }
    }

    public String createPassword() {
        // write code that returns a randomized password
        return this.password;
    }
}
```

and this is what I have in main:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PasswordRandomizer randomizer = new PasswordRandomizer(13);
        System.out.println("Password: " + randomizer.createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + randomizer.createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + randomizer.createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + randomizer.createPassword());
    }
}
```

I would get an output like this:

```
Password: seggdpsptkxqo
Password: seggdpsptkxqo
Password: seggdpsptkxqo
Password: seggdpsptkxqo
```

Feel free to point out any other mistakes or bad habits I have, I'm still pretty new at this.

Comment: you are computing the password in the constructor, not in the "create" method ;)

Comment: Move the actual creating code from the constructor into its own method or into your createPassword method

Comment: I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings. Take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: You need `nextInt(26)` by the way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at your code.

In your constructor, you initialize your length, and then you generate your password:

```
public PasswordRandomizer(int length) {
    // Initialize the variable
    password = "";
    this.length = length;
    while (this.password.length() < this.length) {
        this.symbol = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(this.random.nextInt(25));
        this.password += symbol;
    }
}
```

Then, in your `createPassword` method, you just return that password you generated in the constructor, without changing it:

```
public String createPassword() {
    // write code that returns a randomized password
    return this.password;
}
```

And so, every time you call `createPassword`, you are going to get the same thing. Let's see what happens if we just move that code which generates the password down into the `createPassword` method:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PasswordRandomizer {
    // Define the variables
    private int length;
    private String password;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private char symbol;

    public PasswordRandomizer(int length) {
        // Initialize the variable
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String createPassword() {
        // write code that returns a randomized password
        password = "";
        while (this.password.length() < this.length) {
            this.symbol = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(this.random.nextInt(26));
            this.password += symbol;
        }
        return this.password;
    }

}
```

Now, when we run your `Program`, you get output like:

```
Password: mvlqqgfmotldc
Password: inneuyuynqakd
Password: hstlfsfspfaua
Password: jgngsmdiguxcy
```

Comment: Much appreciated, very good explanation. Could you tell me why I have to have password = ""; in the create password?

Comment: @user3261806 You can find that out yourself by removing that line.

Comment: @user3261806 - Sure. Let's think through it together. 
Imagine if we take it out entirely. (You might try this on your own.) We will get a `NullPointerException` when why try to call `this.password.length()`. 
Now, let's imagine we move it back up to the constructor. Now, every time we call `createPassword()`, we get the same password again. Why do you think this might be?
Well, look at how we are generating our password. `while (this.password.length() < this.length)`. If the previous password is still there, then we won't enter this `while` loop at all.

Comment: Going to need `nextInt(26)`

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new PasswordRandomizer program, otherwise, you will not create a password each time. For instance, if you don't rewrite the PasswordRandomizer class, you can do :

```
package test;
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Password: " + new PasswordRandomizer(13).createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + new PasswordRandomizer(13).createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + new PasswordRandomizer(13).createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + new PasswordRandomizer(13).createPassword());
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be good paired with a rename of `createPassword` to just `getPassword()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Apache Commons Lang library.

In the RandomStringUtils there is a method to generate a random String with a certain length: randomAlphabetic(int count)

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#randomAlphabetic-int-